# TSQL Inner select using outer join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a query that is working for the most part until I had to add the inner select for "Trainers".

As you can see in the code below, I am trying to get all of the trainers for each of the segment ID's.

I am getting an error on the first inner selects where clause `WHERE  trn.segmentID = tes.teSegmentID` saying that tes.teSegmentID is not defined.

Is there another way to approach this query in order to get the trainers like I am trying to accomplish?

```
SELECT *,
   (SELECT e2.[FirstName] AS trainerFirst,
           e2.[LastName] AS trainerLast
    FROM   BS_Training_Trainers AS trn
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           employeeTable AS e2
           ON trn.trainerEmpID = e2.EmpID
    WHERE  trn.segmentID = tes.teSegmentID
    FOR    XML PATH ('trainer'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('trainers'))
FROM   dbo.BS_TrainingEvents AS a
WHERE  a.trainingEventID IN (SELECT tes.trainingEventID
                         FROM   dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_Segments AS tes
                                INNER JOIN
                                dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails AS tesd
                                ON tesd.segmentID = tes.teSegmentID
                                INNER JOIN
                                dbo.BS_LocaleCodes AS locale
                                ON locale.localeID = tesd.localeID
                         WHERE  locale.location = 'Baltimore');
```

Comment: Forget all these nested selects - they make your code extremely opaque both to human readers and to SQL engines, as well as error prone. Learn to write and use simple joins in the wave pool before venturing into the open ocean.

Comment: I have multiple results returned per join, that's why I am doing inner selects. This is a very small piece of the big picture

Comment: Show a sample of what your tables look like; what their DDL is; and what the intended result would look like. I have no idea from your SQL what you are trying to do, as I cannot imagine ever writing such a beast.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're taking the scenic route towards this:

```
SELECT a.*,
X.[FirstName],
X.[LastName]

FROM dbo.BS_TrainingEvents AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT e2.[FirstName], e2.[LastName], locale.location FROM dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_Segments AS tes 
                INNER JOIN dbo.BS_Training_Trainers AS trn ON trn.segmentID = tes.teSegmentID
                INNER JOIN dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails AS tesd ON tesd.segmentID = tes.teSegmentID
                INNER JOIN dbo.BS_LocaleCodes AS locale ON locale.localeID = tesd.localeID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN employeeTable AS e2 ON trn.trainerEmpID = e2.EmpID) AS X ON a.trainingEventID = X.trainingEventID

WHERE  X.location = 'Baltimore';
```

Not sure if I got all those joins right, it was hard to decode from all the nesting you have going on.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This would work fine if there was only 1 trainer per event. It's the reason I had a nested selected as 1 event can have multiple trainers.

Comment: Ok, I made some edits. This uses a single nested select to get the first and last name of the employee for each "event". You should also be able to grab the locale in that statement for use in the where clause. Let me know if this is going in the right direction.

Comment: Ah crap, I reread your comment and I realize this won't give multiple trainers per event.

Answer (score 0):

If I have guessed table relationships from their names correctly, the only way to solve this is to reference the same filtering condition twice: first, in the XML generation part, and second in the outer level of the query:

```
with cte as (
    select distinct tes.trainingEventID, tes.teSegmentID
    from dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_Segments AS tes
        INNER JOIN dbo.BS_TrainingEvent_SegmentDetails AS tesd ON tesd.segmentID = tes.teSegmentID
        INNER JOIN dbo.BS_LocaleCodes AS locale ON locale.localeID = tesd.localeID
    WHERE locale.location = 'Baltimore'
)
SELECT a.*, (
    SELECT e2.[FirstName] AS trainerFirst, e2.[LastName] AS trainerLast
    FROM BS_Training_Trainers AS trn
        LEFT OUTER JOIN employeeTable AS e2 ON trn.trainerEmpID = e2.EmpID
        inner join cte c on trn.segmentID = c.teSegmentID
    FOR XML PATH ('trainer'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('trainers')
    )
FROM dbo.BS_TrainingEvents AS a
where exists (select 0 from cte c where c.testrainingEventID = a.trainingEventID);
```

It's difficult to tell whether this is completely correct, of course, but I hope you get the idea.

Oh yes, and if you would have an event with multiple Baltimore segments, you will never be able to tell which trainer takes which one. But you can always add more data into XML to resolve this.